# clojure way on flow control statement

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a python function like this:

```
def required(value):
    if value is None:
        throw Exception
    if isintance(value, str) and not value:
        throw Exception
    return value
```

Basically I want to check if the value is null or not. If the value is a String, also check if it's empty or not.

What is the clojure way of doing something like this?

Comment: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/cond

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Clojure way of doing something like this is *not* to throw exceptions or so. The idiomatic way would be something that returns `nil` and nothing else.

So my advise: Do this without exceptions.

Your function will then look like this:

```
(defn required [value]
  (when (string? value)
    value))
```

It checks for the type of value and returns `nil` if it is not a String. Otherwise return your value.

**Or** if you want an error message in your terminal:

```
(defn required [value]
  (if (string? value)
    value
    (println "Value must be a String.")))
```

Note that `println` prints the String and then returns again `nil`.

Comment: I liked very much the explained reasons into the context

Comment: Useful perspective, but I don't think we can say without a specific use case. In some cases you'd just be punting the type or null pointer error until later when the error would more usefully be caught earlier. In other cases, you really do want to do a maybe with nil.

Comment: You're totally right, without use case we can just guess what he wants the code for. But with his words "what is the clojure way" my answer above came into my mind.

Answer (score 5):

Preconditions would do the trick nicely in this instance. Otherwise use Clojure's control flow special forms/macros, e.g. `if`, `cond` with `throw`.

```
user=> (defn required 
         [value] 
         {:pre [(string? value) (not-empty value)]} 
         value)
#'user/required

user=> (required nil)
AssertionError Assert failed: (string? value)  user/required ...

user=> (required "")
AssertionError Assert failed: (not-empty value) ...

user=> (required "foo")
"foo"
```

Comment: Note: As [dAni points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232608/1756702), I am likely misinterpreting you, so I made this a CW. If you are writing a function that accepts either non-empty strings or empty collections or anything else non-nil then this is probably a sign you need to refactor.

Answer (score 4):

Both previous answers are slightly wrong on the assertions. I what Budi is asking for is:

```
(defn required [value]
  (if (or (nil? value)
          (and (string? value) (clojure.string/blank? value)))
    (throw (Exception.))
    value))
```

Comment: The first condition is redundant because `nil` is not a String. But, you used better functions for the conditions, which I will steal :).

Comment: Actually, `blank?` is not the same as empty.

Comment: The first condition is not redundant as I understand that (required {:foo :bar}) should return {:foo :bar} and (required 1) should return 1. I used blank? because is more likely to be what Budi wants.

Answer (score 2):

A. Webb is right on the money in that pre-conditions are a great, idiomatic way to represent what you're trying to do here.

For what it's worth, here is how you would do the same thing using explicit exception-throwing and a `cond`ition statement:

```
(defn required [value]
  (cond
    (not (string? value))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Value must be a string."))

    (empty? value)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "String cannot be empty."))

    :else
    value))
```

Or, perhaps more idiomatically, handle the errors first using `when`, then return the value at the end:

```
(defn required [value]
  (when (not (string? value))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Value must be a string.")))
  (when (empty? value)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "String cannot be empty.")))
  value)
```